# Syntax to dereference and assign a Pointer in Delphi

Tags: delphi, pointers

Need to implement an interface method where a Pointer is passed and it is expected to dereference the Pointer and assign to it an OleVariant. Whats the syntax to do this?

```
// Code I have no access to change
function GetEntry: string;
var
  value: OleVariant;
begin
  Entry(@value);  
  Result := VarToStr(value);
end;

// My code  
procedure Entry(Value: Pointer);
begin
  Value^ := ??? // Not sure whats the syntax here in order to assign an OleVariant
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a value cast like this:

```
OleVariant(Value^) := ...
```

Alternatively you can cast the pointer:

```
POleVariant(Value)^ := ...
```